# List<A> containing List<B> containing List<C>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a structure resembling following.

```
class A    
{    
    string title;    
    List<B> bItem;    
}

class B    
{    
    int price;    
    List<C> cItem;    
}

class C    
{    
    int quantity;    
}
```

`List<A>` contains about 200,000 instances of "A";

Now Object "A" is such that it contains a list of "B" and object "B" contain a list of "C";  I have multiple instances of `List<A>` as well. Now I want to find all "A"s in a List having such "B"s and all "B"s having such "C"s containing `quantity > 500`;

The problem I am facing is to specify target for LINQ.

If I use `listA[0].listB[6].listC` then it limits my search to only the mentioned target but I want to search for whole object "listA".

---

Thanx for replying. As I am using hierarchical object so I cannot directly access data by specifying a.bitem or c.quality. so to approach c.quality, I have to do aList[index].bList[index].cList[index].quantity. and according to my knowledge I cannot specify directly a.bList or c.quantity or a.bItem.

as in LINQ query, we provide a target body or basic container of data to query and by giving target as "aList[index].bList[index].cList[index].quantity" limits my search container.

I want to search for all instances of quantity in my whole aList object.

if using LINQ to DataSet then we have complete "C" object in a single table so we can query for all c.quantity regardless of their parent. how can do similer in LINQ to object.

Thank you,

Muhammad

Comment: Even after I've edited your question to the best of my ability, it's still very unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit the question further to clarify it.

Comment: Do you need such `A` which contains *at least* 1 `B` which contains *at least* 1 `C` with quantity > 500?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, your question is unclear but it's *possible* that you're looking for:

```
var query = listA.Where(a => a.bItem
                              .All(b => b.cItem.All(c => c.quantity > 500)));
```

In other words, for each `A` check that all B's conform to (all Cs within the B have quantity greater than 500).

Comment: :D was typing this as the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<A> list = new List<A>(...); // assuming

var a500 = from a in list
           from b in a.bItem
           from c in b.cItem
           where c.quantity > 500
           select a;
```

Comment: That will return an A that has *any* B with *any* C with quantity greater than 500. While the qusetion is unclear, the way that I read the question, we only want As where *all* the Bs have Cs which *all* have quantity over 500. (This query will also return the same `A` reference several times, one for each C grandchild.)

Comment: Wont this give multiple A's ?

Comment: @Magnus: It will, shouldn't it? I doubt.

Comment: @Jon: Agree, but I've read the question as "contains at least one", like Magnus's answer.

Comment: @abatishchev I meant multiple of the same A

Comment: @Magnus: Then consumer can call `Distinct()`

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
 var result = aCol.where(a => a.bItem.Any(b => b.cItem.Any(c => c.quantity > 500)));
```